# Camera roll based on distance from follow target

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been working on some player movement code and I need a little help with automating the roll of my player camera. Right now I've got roll changing based on keyboard input (left/right arrows) but I'd like the roll to happen automatically based on the relationship of the camera to the followTarget. In other words as the followTarget goes left or right based on the spline curve it follows and the camera lags behind it a bit resulting in the followTarget pulling away from the camera center either to the left or right. I want to calculate that angle and tie it to the amount of roll. I hope this makes sense. Any help would be super appreciated!

```
            // Calculate the target position based on the follow distance and the target's position
            Vector3 targetPos = followTarget.position + followTarget.forward * -followDistance;

            // Apply smooth damp to the player's position
            Vector3 smoothedPos = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.position, targetPos, ref velocity, smoothTime);

            // Calculate the new local position
            Vector3 localPos = transform.InverseTransformPoint(smoothedPos);
            localPos.x += input.Move.x * movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime * movementRange;
            localPos.y += input.Move.y * movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime * movementRange;

            //Clamp the local position
            localPos.x = Mathf.Clamp(localPos.x, -movementLimit.x, movementLimit.x);  
            localPos.y = Mathf.Clamp(localPos.y, -movementLimit.y, movementLimit.y);

            //Update the player's position
            transform.position = transform.TransformPoint(localPos);
            
            //Match the player's rotation to the follow target's rotation
            transform.rotation = followTarget.rotation;

            //Match the roll of the player to the input
            roll = Mathf.Lerp(roll, input.Move.x * maxRoll, Time.deltaTime * rollSpeed);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(transform.rotation.eulerAngles.x, transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y, roll);
```